# Php - Getting multiple checkbox input

Tags: php, html

I have multiple checkbox in my one of my page

```
<form method="POST" action="flight_cart.php" autocomplete="off">
<table>
    <?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= 5 ; $i++)
        {
            print "<tr>
                    <td><input class='seats' name='seats[$i]' type='checkbox' value=S".$i.">Seat " .$i. "</input></td>
                    <td><input class='special s$i' name='special[]'  type='checkbox' value='noNuts'>No Nuts</input></td>
                    <td><input class='special s$i' name='special[]'  type='checkbox' value='noGluten'>No Gluten</input></td>
                    <td><input class='special s$i' name='special[]'  type='checkbox' value='noCorn'>No corn</input></td>
                    </tr>";
        }
        print "<tr><td><button type='submit' onclick='return submitValidation();'>Add to Bookings</td></tr>";
    ?>
</table>
```

I would like to get the data in the next page using php such as:

Seat S1; NoNuts, NoGluten

Seat S2; NoNuts, NoCorn

So far I was only able to get the array of picked seats

```
<?php

  $booked_seats = $_POST['seats'];
  $special = array();

  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($booked_seats); $i++)
  {
    for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($_POST['special']); $j++)
    {
      $currentValue = $_POST['special'][$j];
      $special[$i][$j] = $currentValue;
    }
  }
```

I would like to store all the data into 2D array. so..

special[1][0] is noNuts

special[1][1] is noGluten

special[2][0] is noNuts

special[2][1] is noCorn

Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what results are you getting now?

Comment: you appear to be the silent type and your acceptance record on answers given also seems to reflect that. You come here asking for help, a comment is given asking for clarification and answers given that stand to also not be accepted. If you want to remain in good standings, you need to cooperate. This is a two-way street, not one.

Comment: Currently I am only able to populate all the special[] value into one array. I did not know how to populate it into a 2D array

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$currentValue = $_POST['special'][$j];
```

To

```
$currentValue = $_POST['special'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
echo "<form action='test.php' method='POST'>";
echo '<table>';
for($i = 1; $i <= 5 ; $i++)
{
    print "<tr>
            <td><input class='seats' name='special[$i]' type='checkbox' value=S".$i.">Seat " .$i. "</input></td>
            <td><input class='special s$i' name='special[$i][]'  type='checkbox' value='noNuts'>No Nuts</input></td>
            <td><input class='special s$i' name='special[$i][]'  type='checkbox' value='noGluten'>No Gluten</input></td>
            <td><input class='special s$i' name='special[$i][]'  type='checkbox' value='noCorn'>No corn</input></td>
            </tr>";
}
print "<tr><td><button type='submit'>Add to Bookings</td></tr>";
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
```

**$_POST content**

```
Array
(
    [special] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => noNuts
                    [1] => noGluten
                    [2] => noCorn
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => noGluten
                    [1] => noCorn
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => noNuts
                    [1] => noGluten
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

concat the $i with spacial

```
<form method="POST" action="flight_cart.php" autocomplete="off">
<table>
    <?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= 5 ; $i++)
        {
            print "<tr>
                    <td><input class='seats' name='seats[$i]' type='checkbox' value=S".$i.">Seat " .$i. "</input></td>
                    <td><input class='special s$i' name='special.$i.[]'  type='checkbox' value='noNuts'>No Nuts</input></td>
                    <td><input class='special s$i' name='special.$i.[]'  type='checkbox' value='noGluten'>No Gluten</input></td>
                    <td><input class='special s$i' name='special.$i.[]'  type='checkbox' value='noCorn'>No corn</input></td>
                    </tr>";
        }
        print "<tr><td><button type='submit' onclick='return submitValidation();'>Add to Bookings</td></tr>";
    ?>
</table>
```

In your code you try to get 2d array of special but in reality it is single arrya...

```
<?php
  $booked_seats = $_POST['seats'];
  $special = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($booked_seats); $i++)
  {

    $currentValue = $_POST['special'.$i]; //concat $i to get perticular seat special.
    for($j = 0; $j < count($currentValue); $j++)
    {
      $special[$i][$j] = $currentValue.$i.[$j];
    }
  }?>
```

Comment: I tried this way. I was able to store it in array but it returns zero when I call var_dump. Thank you anyway